# Aspen Plus slow initializing

Tags: pywin32, win32com, aspen

So I am optimizing Aspen Models via Python and using the win32 library to connect the 2 with each other. I was wondering wether there is a way to speed op the initialization as it takes pretty long (40 seconds everytime I run)

```
self.application = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Apwn.Document')
self.folder_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
self.path = fr"{self.folder_path}\{self.filename}.bkp"
'InitFromFile2 is the one thats very slow'
self.application.InitFromFile2(self.path)
print("End Initializing")`
```